# Какой язык посоветуете учить первым?

Tags: c, php, javascript

Здравствуйте, какой язык посоветуете учить первым? Имею в виду, которые не из веба.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Русский(пунктуацию и орфографию)

Comment: Если серьезно, то многие начинают с TP - не очень сложен и к грамотности построения программ приучает

Comment: Как по мне нет сложных или простых языков(Ассамблер исключение xD). <br>И любой язык можно выучить самому с 0я и начинать можно абсолютно с какого угодно

Comment: Поддержу <a href="http://hashcode.ru/users/3543/only_fallen">@Only_fallen</a>, Turbo Pascal. Хорош для обучения программированию в широком смысле. Освоив один язык, другие осваиваются проще.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно сказал **AlexWindHope** - язык надо выбирать из поставленной задачи, а просто так язык не выучишь. Я начинал с изучения фортрана, фокала, бейсик и ассемблера. Некоторые языки знаю хорошо, потому что учил их сам под какие-то свои задачи. То, что было по программе - практически не знаю. ПОтом появилась необходимость создать сайт выучил html, css, javascript (только то что мне нужно было) и Java2. Сейчас, когда сайты имеют большие объемы и хранят, и обрабатывают базы - решил изучить php. Почему не Java2. Есть один недостаток. Я напичкал свой первый сайт java аплетами, но не у всех установлены VJ, и мои страницы отображались не полноценно... Решил отказаться от Java и выучить php - который обрабатывается сервером.
А вообще языков программирования много. Мне для усовершенствования autoCada неоходимо знать lisp. Так что выбирайте язык по необходимости. Зная какой то один язык хорошо - остальные учить будет легче. Они похожи - отличаются синтаксисом...

З.Ы. что касается ТПаскаля, ничего сказать не могу. Не изучал.

Comment: ная какой то один язык хорошо - остальные учить будет легче. Они похожи - отличаются синтаксисом...<br>Не только им, но реально отлично зная один из языков действительно очень просто изучить любой другой

Answer (score 1):

Просто учить язык ущербное занятие, лучше всего придумать себе задачу и учить язык который лучше всего подходил бы для решения этой задачи. По себе - когда учил в детстве C (а учил просто так, чтобы знать) интереса небыло, все давалось очень туго и убого... В итоге бросил. 
Нормально же начал учить программирование именно тогда когда появилась задача(задача была очень простой - регистрация и авторизация).
Вот когда уже более менее будете знать 1 из языков программирования - тогда уже можете ознакомится с другими языками и, возможно, изменить ваше предпочтение.

Answer (score 0):

Сразу проект не напишешь, найди в интернете цикл обучающих статей по C#, ставь VisualStudio и вперед, набирай примеры программ, пиши и пиши простенькие программы, вскоре воткнешь че к чему)         
По языкам:        
1) Pascal уже достаточно стар, даже в мое время он уже был не актуален        
2) Java хорошо. Еще Java не слишком то отличается от C# за исключением того что в VisualStudio с документацией получше, кудаб ты не навел везде написано что это и для чего.

Answer (score 0):

Если ты хочешь программировать в WINDOWS то не совершай ошибок как все остальные, включая меня, учи именно C++, научись програмить в консоли, как поймешь немедленно переходи в C++ Win32 попрактикуйся создавать приложения с окнами и т.д.  Пойми как устроена виндовс и тогда тебе любой язык дастся с легкостью! С перва никаких бэйсиков паскалей и прочей чуши. А если ты хочешь потом стать реальным профи то сразу после того как поймешь ядро винды переходи на Ассемблер под винду. И хорошо его изучи. Скачай Visual C++ и будет тебе рай

Я  начал с паскаля и делфи! Потому что никто не указал путь истинный в программировании. Теперь понимаю, что я потерял целый год!